# Trading Logic - Exclude Signal from prior days

Tags: excel, excel-formula, algorithmic-trading, trading

I'm working on a trading logic on Excel and can't solve this problem. Just looking for idea on how to approach this problem.

What I'm looking to do is to excludes specific signal that occurred within x days. As an example, if a Buy signal was triggered on 3/1/2021 and I set my parameter to excludes any buy signal from the prior 10 days, the next buy signal can only occurs after 3/11/2021.

My current setup contain 2 columns. First column "BuySignal" check if price exceed specific criteria and apply 1 or 0. Second column Sum the "BuySignal" over the past 10 days. Problem with this method is that signal can occurs many times within that 10 days causing the next buy signal to not be triggered.

[image: sample trading logic]

Comment: Thanks for the update. A very nice question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elegant version using `OFFSET`. Put this in `E3` and copy down:

```
=IF(AND(C3>D3,IFERROR(SUM(OFFSET(E3,-1,,-9)),0)=0),1,0)
=--(AND(C3>D3,IFERROR(SUM(OFFSET(E3,-1,,-9)),0)=0))
```

Less elegant version. If you post this in `E16` and copy it up and down, it will work:

```
=IF(AND(C16>D16,IFERROR(SUM(E7:E15)=0,0)),1,0)
```

Comment: you're a wizard. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. But look, I also finally made it using `OFFSET` :)